# Asp.Net Razor Page cannot display image

Tags: asp.net-core, https, mixed-content

My project is Asp.net Core App with framework 5 and
problem is that I can't display image using a virtual directory
Example code:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div  class="text-center" >
    //Doesn't work
    <img src="http://mnpalvelin.com/GT_nayttelykuvat/thumb_kuva1.jpg" width="500" />

</div>
<div>

    //this settings work normally
    <img src="~/nayttelykuvat/thumb_kuva1.jpg" width="500" />
</div>
```

Is it really so that images have to be located on the same website as pages.

Comment: You can check this doc to know more about "mixed content blocking": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content

Answer (score 0):

[image: Snippet from Google Chrome Developer Tools]

When running you app it is loaded over SSL using the HTTPS Protocol. Therefore the Browser prohibts images and other resources to be loaded over HTTP. Thats because it enforces that every asset is loaded using the same protocol. Therefore the Get request to show your image gets upgraded to HTTPS but because this URL doesnt exist the image cant be displayed.